# Remove hover state from the menu icon on bootstrap nav dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created nav menu with Bootstrap v3.0.0 and I want to make it collapse when display resolution less than some value. Everuthing is ok, except for one thing - after click on collapsed menu button, button remains in the `hover` state. 
Here my html for button:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header_st" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" id="toggle_footer_dropdown" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse_footer">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <span class="navbar-brand" id="about_footer_links">
             <i>Show links</i>
           </span>
     </div>
...

</nav>
```

How can I reset hover state for this button?

Comment: No CSS?...it would be helpful.

Comment: Looks like there only bootstrap.css on this page.

Comment: I assume you must have changed **something** otherwise this wouldn't happen.

Comment: It does not have the hover state any more, it now has the focus state. Because it it a button, once you have clicked on it, it has focus. If you then click somewhere else the menu will stay open but the toggle will lose focus and go back to the other style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have the hover state any more, it now has the focus state. Because it it a button, once you have clicked on it, it has focus. If you then click somewhere else the menu will stay open but the toggle will lose focus and go back to the other style. If you want to change the focus style but keep[ the hover style, you could try the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please add the following code to your css:

```
@ media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     . navbar-toggle:hover {
         background-color: transparent! important;
     }
}
```

Hope that helps ..!

Answer (score 0):

find .nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus and clear the background color in bootstrap css file you are using (or overwrite it in your own css stylesheet)

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #eee; <-- delete that line
}
```